# Optimizing out a VS 2022 dependency in a Github CI action

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, github-actions, stdformat

I've made some Github CI actions, but I was having trouble compiling my project on windows using the Visual Studio version (VS2019). Specifically, I was getting errors related to `std::format_strings` not being defined (The local build on my PC works just fine, although I'm using VS 2022 here).

To remedy this issue I've proceeded to download VS 2022 into my [action](https://github.com/Goubermouche/sigma/actions/runs/7240286699/workflow). While this does work, and my project compiles just fine, it obviously takes very long and isn't optimal at all (the action takes roughly 10 minutes, where 8 minutes are taken by the VS install).

**Is there a way to optimize my GitHub action for the windows environment so that I can get closer to the performance of my Linux builds (~2 minutes)?**

```
name: Windows

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0

    - name: Install Visual Studio Build Tools
      run: |
        choco install visualstudio2022buildtools --package-parameters "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.BuildTools --includeOptional" -y
        choco install visualstudio2022-workload-vctools -y
    - name: Add MSBuild to PATH
      run: |
        echo "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH
    - name: Print MSBuild Version
      run: |
        msbuild -version
    - name: Run Premake for Visual Studio
      run: .\setup.bat

    - name: Compile Project with MSBuild
      run: |
        msbuild sigma.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="x64" /p:stdcpp=latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved - windows-2022 provides a VS2022 install, I just misread another error and thought that it does not.